# Can PHPUnit code coverage produce HTML diff of two coverages that correspond to two git commits

Tags: git, phpunit, code-coverage, diff

In the same sense that when I want to review code, I am reviewing only changes, I would also be interested only in the changes of unit coverage. So, what I'd like to see is the difference of the code coverage of two commits in git.

I am aware that there are 3rd party solutions to produce diff of any two HTML files, but I was wondering whether there was something native to PHPUnit that would allow something like this?

If there is not, I'm aware PHPUnit can produce coverage in other formats other than HTML.  Would you suggest producing diff in some other format, and than diffing it? I wouldn't suspect to get much better results, but was wondering just in case.